# Two sentences in the same footer on every page

Tags: footnotes, fancyhdr

I need to include a footnote on every page. The footnote contains two lines.

**Expected output:**

*** This is only for members**

**^ This is only for leaders**

Currently I'm only able to print one line at a time, the second line is getting ignored

**Current output:**

*** This is only for members**

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{
\ifnum\thepage=1 \else \footnotesize \textit 
{*This is only for members} 
\fi}
```

What's the change needed to include two lines in the same footnote, on all pages except the first page?

Also - could you also share the syntax to have these in all the pages excluding the if condition? The "/footsize" comment is not being accepted without the if clause, is this expected?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm guessing an error occurred because you were using `^` as-is in your code, which is only allowed in math-mode.

Answer (score 3):

Stack the entries in the footer using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\else
    \footnotesize\itshape
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l}
      * This is only for members \\
      \detokenize{^} This is only for leaders
    \end{tabular}
  \fi}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Note the condition using `\value{page}` instead of `\thepage`. This to ensure you're not conditioning on the *representation* of the `page` counter, but rather it's actual `value`. The representation could be different (for example, `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}`, like in a document with `\frontmatter` set).

Comment: You might be interested in using `\textsuperscript{*}`.

Comment: You also have to decide if you want to have page numbers and where.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler solution that does not use explicit tests.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize\itshape%
  \textsuperscript{*}~This is only for members\\%
  \^~This is only for leaders}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```